# I am looking for sql statements for below statements

Tags: sql, oracle, duplicates, rows

I am looking for writing SQL statements for the below problems

1. To remove duplicate rows
2. To select rows from 10 to 15 order by a column length

They need to be generic SQL statements not specific to SQL Server or Oracle.

Can anybody quickly help me please ?

So far I tried the below

Assuming the table is called `sample` with columns `id int`, and `word varchar(50)`

Query #1:

```
delete from [sample] a
where a.rowid > any (select b.rowid 
                     from [SAMPLE] b 
                     where a.word = b.word)
```

Query #2:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [SAMPLE] 
WHERE rownum <= 5 AND rowid NOT IN (SELECT ROWID 
                                    FROM [sample] 
                                    ORDER BY LENGTH(WORD) 
                                    WHERE rownum >= 10);
```

Are they correct ? I am new to SQL programming

Thanks a lot for your time

Comment: Which RDBMS are you trying to run these in?  Unfortunately, I don't believe there is a generic solution to get the row number, it's going to be database specific.  Given your syntax, it looks more like oracle.

Comment: Yeah..I would be fine to find a query to suit oracle.

Comment: Do really mean duplicate rows, i.e. exactly the same row twice? Or just a row which violates the Primary Key of the table (because you didn't implement it)?

Comment: Not exactly duplicate rows. The rows that have duplicate content on a specific column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) Your query is pretty close. In Oracle:

```
delete from sample s
    where s.rowid > (select min(s2.rowid) from sample s2 where s.word = s2.word)
```

SQL Server doesn't have a `rowid` pseudo-column.  If you have a unique id, the following will work in both databases:

```
delete from sample s
    where s.id > (select min(s2.id) from sample s2 where s.word = s2.word)
```

(2) The most recent versions of SQL Server and Oracle both support the ANSI standard `FETCH` syntax.  So, something like this:

```
select t.*
from table t
order by length(t.col)
offset 10 fetch next 6 rows;
```

The problem is the `length()` versus `len()` function.  These are different in the two databases.  Your best bet would be to create a user defined function in one of the databases to mimic the functionality of the other.

Comment: Thanks Gordon Linoff. I appreciate your time spent on answering my question.

Answer (score 0):

For row number, if you have a sortable Key, (a unique column or set of columns) you can do this:

```
Select (Select count(*) from table
       Where keyColumn <= thisRow.KeyColumn) rowNum
From table thisRow
Order by keyColumn
```

It's expensive, but its generic.

To remove duplicate rows, a similar twist works:

```
Delete From table
Where keyColumn Not in
   (Select Max(KeyColumn) -- or Min(KeyColumn)
    From table
    Group By [All Columns other than KeyColumn]
    having count(*) > 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove duplicates there many methods. This one works well.

```
delete from sample a
where a.rowid not in (select min(b.rowid) 
                      from sample b 
                      group by word)
```

Answer (score 0):

For #1 the generic way to remove duplicate rows is as following:

1. create a copy of the table as a temporary table
2. INSERT in temp table SELECT from base table GROUP BY all columns HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
3. DELETE FROM baseTable using the rows from the temp table
4. INSERT in base table SELECT from temp

For #2 most DBMSes support Windowed Aggregate Functions:

```
SELECT *
FROM
 (
   SELECT 
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CHAR_LENGTH(word)) AS rn
     ,...
   FROM [SAMPLE]
 ) dt
WHERE rn BETWEEN 10 AND 15
```